# How can I compare a "sub id" with a documment id?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm new to typescript and I'm migrating a existing project to it. On this projects I have some middleware functions that are on separate files.

This is one of the functions:

```
const checkCampgroundOwnership = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  if (req.user && req.isAuthenticated()) {
    try {
      const foundCampground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);

      // does user own the campground?
      if (foundCampground && foundCampground.author.id.equals(req.user._id)) {
        next();
      } else {
        req.flash("error", "You don't have permission to do that");
        res.redirect("back");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      req.flash("error", "Campground not found");
      return res.redirect("back");
    }
  } else {
    req.flash("error", "You need to be logged in to do that");
    return res.redirect("back");
  }
};
```

My problem is on line 11, where I check if there's a foundCampground and if it's author id is the same of the user, who is logged in, id. However, I'm getting is error: `Property 'equals' does not exist on type 'string'`. What I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi you can just use simple use comparison operator like this

```
if (foundCampground && foundCampground.author.id == req.user._id) {
    next();
  } else {
    req.flash("error", "You don't have permission to do that");
    res.redirect("back");
  }
```

it will work for you just fine. you can also check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) for more detail info about comparison operator